# How to get sum of amount of distinct name

Tags: django, django-orm

```
poi = booking_models.TestBooking.objects.filter(customer_visit=instance).values_list("package__package_name", "amount").order_by("package").distinct()
```

Output of poi = `[(None, 392.0), (None, 530.0), ('RahulNewPaackage', 3999.0), ('Suraj pkg today all', 699.0), ('suraj 44', 599.0)]`

So i want to get sum of these amounts. So sum will be 6219. I tried aggregate method but it does not work with order_by and without order_by distinct() does not work. So How to achieve this. Thank you !!

Comment: Have you tried `booking_models.TestBooking.objects.filter(customer_visit=instance).values("amount").distinct().annotate(total=Sum('amount'))` and don't forget to import `from django.db.models import Sum`

Comment: Yes i tried. It does not work. It only shows the same amount in total like this - [{'amount': 599.0, 'total': 599.0}, {'amount': 599.0, 'total': 599.0}]

Comment: remove `distinct` and try

Comment: Nope. Not working. However i found another way to do it but thank you for giving time.

Comment: What i would like to know

Comment: You extract every second element from the list. Then get the sum of the list.